# setEditing method delete button doesn't work

Tags: swift, uitableview

In my `UIViewController`, I have an `UITableView` which contains different cells with saved contents by using the `NSUserDefaults`. I also have a custom `UIBarButtonItem` which causes the `UITableView` to enter and leave editing mode.

This all works, but the problem is when I tap the round red button and on the right side of the cell appears the delete button, the delete button doesn't work... I can tap on it as much as I want but the cell does not get deleted.

```
@IBAction func EditListButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if ShoppingListTable.editing {
        ShoppingListTable.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        self.EditListButton.title = "Edit"
    } else {
        ShoppingListTable.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        self.EditListButton.title = "Done"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UITableViewDataSource`'s [`tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:) to detect a tap on the delete button.

Then in the implementation delete the row from your data source (`NSUserDefaults` in your case).

So in your tableView's dataSource (ie. in the class you implemented `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` for example), add your custom implementation of `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` where you delete the underlying data.

Comment: Do I have to write that in a function? If not then where? Very new to programming sorry

Comment: I edited the answer to be a bit more explicit. Yes, you have to provide your custom implementation of the method. Just like you did for `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong.. Can you please write the code that I need? I'm just developping an app for personal use and learning swift language